# Cannot submit form drawn by Rails Turbo Frame response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo, turbo-frames

A form inside a turbo_frame is blocked from being submitted a second time.

Both the current page and the form action are the same path.
I see forms now have to redirect to a new location or return an error code: [turbo/pull/39](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/39).

**I have a form on every index view sending a GET request to the index action, which filters the records based on the url query parameters. This works great. Is this no longer possible with latest Rails?** Is there a workaround that could be applied here, to avoid creating a new route for the form action?

These are idempotent filter/search requests, hence the GET method. A form is a handy way to collect and send the filter values. Is it correct/intentional that Rails with Hotwire insists on a redirect in this scenario?

**Update:**
It works if I submit the form as xhr instead of using Turbo. I add `local: false` and `data-turbo: false` to the form. Then add index.js.erb with `document.getElementByID(<id of turbo frame>)` and set its `outerHTML` to the rendered partial. Not sure if this will stop working due to deprecated ujs features (maybe [mrujs](https://mrujs.com/) can step in then).

Comment: Does it help to add a dummy parameter like "now: (new Date()).getTime()" to produce a different get every time ? No experience with hotwire but it's what I use in my javascript when I send stuff to the server.

Comment: No it's the same when params are different in each request